# Approver Comments to be mapped with a field named "Comments" on Opportunity

Tags: approval-process

I have a requirement in which I need to map the approver comments to a fields on the Opportunity Object but without code. Can somebody help me achieve it?

Comment: have you checked this link [https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BBE2IAO](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BBE2IAO)?

Comment: Is there no way to do without code? I knew this methodology.

Comment: I think trigger is only possible way to achieve this.I have posted this as an answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have limited option.We can not create workflows on the ProcessInstanceStep object where the comments get saved so we can not do field update.

So possibly trigger is the only way to get through this.You can see the object hierarchy here.This might be helpful for you in writing trigger.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_process.htm